# MySQL: Updatable VIEW with derived column; Equivalent functionality of "INSTEAD OF UPDATE" Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to have a view that has a derived column.  For example I have a table with fields: Qty and Price.  My view then has those fields as well as a calculated field Qty*Price.

I'm using MySQL.  As I understand it, MySQL doesn't allow the view to be editable if there is a derived table (Updatable and Insertable Views -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html).

When I was working with sqlite, I was able to get around this by creating an "INSTEAD OF UPDATE" trigger (for example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4507202/1029698) stackoverflow response).  However, MySQL apparently doesn't allow this type of trigger.  (MySQL Trigger Syntax -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Are there any other ways I could get this kind of functionality with MySQL -- namely a view with a derived column that is also editable?  Obviously, I can do it on the application side without the view, but I would much prefer it on the DB side if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a `subtotal` column, with `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers to set its value to Qty*Price?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work.  Sort of seems inelegant to store a calculated value in the database.  But it would probably be a straightforward way to get the job done.

Comment: Oh, I'd cache that value over views every stinkin' time.